# Reading Yahoo Mails with PHP is possible?

Tags: php, yahoo-mail

Basicly what I'm trying to do:
1- login to Yahoo Mail.
2- getting mails (with both content and sender) into a string.

I'm able to send emails (from Yahoo Mail) by using phpmailer class. But I haven't done anything for reading mails. Also I couldn't find any useful information. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, use the Yahoo! Mail API.

To get the last three messages use this query

```
select * from ymail.messages where numMid='3'
```

http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/